# Excel (VBA): Going through rows for specific date range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

First of all: I'm just an average Excel user (so not really experienced with formulas and I just heard of VBA as a possible solution).

I have a table with dates (can be multiple ones for each day) and Values for these dates. I now want to get the SUM of all dates of each week (e.g. 8th May-14th May are calendar week 19, so all values belonging to that week should be added to the SUM value of week 19 [red box]).
This also should be a one-time setup, so that I can just apply that for all following weeks.

Is there a possible way to solve that with just Excel formulas or do I need VBA (some formulas or/and code would be great!)

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add another column to show the week number. Then it is easily done with `SUMIF`.

The formula in `C2` is `=WEEKNUM(A2,2)`. This starts the week on Monday, as your highlighting above shows. (The week numbers are different than what you show. If you want, you can add a `-1` at the end.)

The formula in `F2` is `=SUMIF(C$2:C$24,E2,B$2:B$24)`, then drag it down for future weeks.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try formula - `weeknum` to get values in your *"week"* column, then use `sumif` to get values.

It will be like below;

Make a column called Week-Number: `=WEEKNUM("Date Column", 2)` The number 2 assumes that Monday is the first day of the week.

And then apply <kbd>Remove Duplicates</kbd> on that column, and get the Week column.

For column called value use this formula: `=SUMIF("Week-Number Column","="&"Week Column (each row)", "Value Column")`

Look at the pictures below; First one shows the answers and the second one shows the formulas:

[image: Values]

[image: Formulas]

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't quiet figure out how to go trough every row until the date gives back another week 'number'.
If I want to to it for only one row it's: `=IF(WEEKNUM(A1; 21)=D1; WEEKNUM(A1))` But it needs to not only go this one row…

Comment: refer to mrsundquist's answer, what you need to do is select row C, and Click menu :     data - filter - advanced,  and retrieve the distinct values to row E